react native 0.63.5 library development symlink always hard/full reload - not hot reload work
react native 0.63.5 library development yarn symlink always hard/full reload app even small change - not hot reload work.
I tried
* node_modoules remove and install
* rm -rf ~/.config/yarn/link/* 
* watchman watch-del-all
* rm -rf .git/index.lock
* restart devices

package.json
{
    "name": "TestProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "android:dev": "yarn android & adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
        "check-code": "prettier --check miniApps/* && eslint miniApps/**/*.{ts,tsx} --max-warnings=0",
        "code-format": "prettier --loglevel warn --write miniApps/*",
        "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007",
        "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
        "buildMiniApp": "plop"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.0",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^12.3.6",
        "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.4",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.7.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.7.0",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.4",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.0",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.7",
        "@sentry/react-native": "^1.4.5",
        "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
        "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
        "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
        "add": "^2.0.6",
        "ajv": "^7.1.0",
        "appcenter": "^3.0.3",
        "appcenter-analytics": "^3.0.3",
        "appcenter-crashes": "^3.0.3",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "0.63.5",
        "react-native-camera": "^3.26.0",
        "react-native-config": "^1.4.1",
        "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
        "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.7",
        "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.2.1",
        "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^1.2.5",
        "react-native-floating-action": "^1.21.0",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
        "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
        "react-native-input-spinner": "^1.2.10",
        "react-native-localize": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
        "react-native-network-logger": "^1.13.0",
        "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
        "react-native-track-player": "^2.1.3",
        "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
        "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
        "yarn": "^1.22.4",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2",
        "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^5.3.23",
        "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.23",
        "@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.23",
        "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.4.3",
        "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.0.2",
        "@types/i18n-js": "^3.0.3",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.150",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/qs": "^6.9.5",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
        "@types/react-native-honeywell-scanner": "^1.0.0",
        "@types/react-native-input-spinner": "^1.2.0",
        "@types/react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.2",
        "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
        "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "faker": "^5.4.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.0",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
        "plop": "^3.0.5",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4",
        "qs": "^6.9.4",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "./jest/jest-preset.js",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "./jest/setup.js",
            "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": []
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./assets/fonts/"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-push": "yarn check-code"
        }
    }
}


metro.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: true,
            },
        }),
    },
    // path of react native library project
    watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../sc-mobile-design-system/packages')],
};

```js
bable.consig.js

module.exports = {
presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
plugins: [
[
'module-resolver',
{
root: ['./'],
alias: {
'@miniApps': './miniApps',
'@components': './components',
'@theme': './theme',
'@screens': './screens',
'@context': './context',
'@i18n': './i18n',
'@services': './services',
'@types': './types',
'@utils': './utils',
'@svgs': './SVGs',
'@fbnInbound': './miniApps/FBNInbound',
'@hooks': './hooks',
'@fbnManifest': './miniApps/FBNManifest',
'@nimInboundPutaway': './miniApps/NIMInboundPutaway',
'@fbnSortition': './miniApps/FBNSortition',
'@fbnPicking': './miniApps/FBNPicking',
'@fbnReplenishment': './miniApps/FBNReplenishment',
'@ndr': './miniApps/Ndr'
},
},
],
],
};

